# Domain driven design: allowed logic in application services

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a question of how to better organize the implementation of the following functionality.
Suppose a **user** needs to be registered into the system by **unique** email and password (first step) and then he should confirm registration (second step). I have several choices of structuring implementation of first step (registration) between application services/domain services/**user** entity and I'm not sure which one is better.

**First option:**

AppService:

```
var existingUser = UserRepository.GetUserByEmail(email);

if (existingUser != null)
{
    throw new ValidationException(...);
}

var newUser = UserFactory.CreateUser();

newUser.Register(email, password);

UserRepository.Save(newUser);

// commit
```

So here, we do not use any domain service. The thing which I personally don't feel confortable is that Email uniqueness business rule is checked in the Application Service, this being a business rule.

**Second option:**

AppService:

```
var user = UserRegistrationDomainService.RegisterUser(email, password);

UserRepository.Save(user);

// commit
```

UserRegistrationDomainService:

```
User RegisterUser(email, password)
{
  var existingUser = UserRepository.GetUserByEmail(email);

  if (existingUser != null)
  {
    throw new ValidationException(...);
  }

  var newUser = UserFactory.CreateUser();

  newUser.Register(email, password);

  return newUser;
```

}

What I don't like here, is that this solution is not quite symmetric with the implementation of second step, where we just get the user from repository and call User.ConfirmRegistration(). So for registration confirmation we do not need any domain service whereas for registration, in second option, we use such service.

Which option is better? Can the application service from first option contain email uniqueness validation?

Comment: This belongs to the facade to the "membership" system, be that a service or something else. I have read the book and practised the words, but I've come to realise that DDD can cause harm if not well understood. It drives programmers to apply "recipes" as they would design patterns rather than create solutions to the problems at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the Validation for that lives in the Domain (either the Entity of the service).  The rule after all, is required due to a business rule.

It would be preferable in option 2 for the application services not to be responsible for saving the user, this is blurring the lines of responsibilities and it would be nicer if the domain service handled it. And the application service would simply call `UserRegistrationDomainService.RegisterUser(email, password)`

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 means that the unique email rule is application-specific. In other words, if you take the Domain dll (or jar, module, etc.) to reuse it in another application, the rule won't be there any more.

Since we can reasonably consider that rule to be application-agnostic, I'd choose option 2.

Another solution could be to implement it in the Factory instead. After all, this is where you'll typically put the validation logic upon creation of your User (null/empty name checking, email format verification, and so on) so why not centralize all creation rules in the same place ?